# concatenate characters and convert to int

Tags: c#

i am using c# and i need some help in this...
i have 2 strings

```
s1="1234"
s2="5678"
```

i want to create 2 integers so that they become equal to the 1st 2 characters and convert to int. ie

```
int i1=12  12 is the 1st 2 characters from s1
int i2=56  56 is the 1st 2 characters from s2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
int i1 = Convert.ToInt32(s1.Substring(0, 2));
int i2 = Convert.ToInt32(s2.Substring(0, 2));
```

You'll have to add various checks, though (say, what happens if the length of either string is less than 2? or if they contain something other than digits?)

Comment: o wait....
i tried this, but it gave an error:
 i tried to do this but an error occured:

string s = "11/6/2009 12:00:00 AM";
int i=Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(3,2));

Answer (score 0):

```
int i1 = Convert.ToInt32(s1.substring(0,2));
```

And the same for i2 of course, obviously not great using hard-coded index of 2, but you could specify that in some other way through user input or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

```
int i1 = int.parse(s1.SubString(0,2));
int i2 = int.parse(s2.SubString(0,2));
```